# Why in Laravel 5.8 is unable to create a directory?

Tags: php, permissions, laravel-5.8

In a custom Command I am runnind the following piece of code:

```
$path='REP-001';
Storage::disk('reports')->makeDirectory($path,'0777',true,true);
```

And the `reports` has the following configuration inside the `filesystems.php` config:

```
return [
    'reports' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'       => storage_path('reports'),
            'visibility' => '0766',
        ],
];
```

But the diurectory is not created. If I run upon a shell:

```
ls -l storage
```

I retrieve the following:

```
drwxrwxr-x    4 www-data www-data      4096 Jul 30 14:49 app
drwxrwxr-x    2 www-data www-data      4096 Jul 30 08:52 logs
drwxrw-rw-    2 www-data www-data      4096 Jul 30 15:00 reports
```

Despite having right permissions to write I am unable to do so. Any ideas why?

Comment: hm, I think, you find  in reports/REP-001. just ls -l storage/reports

Comment: The issu is that an `ls ./storage/reports` shows no folders inside.